# Is Ubuntu "spyware" in the others *buntu too?

Tags: ubuntu

I have recently discovered about the "spyware" Canonical has put in the search bar in Unity. Although it is easily turned off, it is very unpleasant to use a system that did that. Since Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu and others are official variants from Canonical's Ubuntu, I wonder if they also have it somewhere in their systems, or just the original Ubuntu.

Comment: It has to sync the time from somewhere, so yes it dials out for quite a few reasons you probably didn't know about in all flavors.

Comment: @Mateo kos' answer makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The "spyware" is built-in into Unity's Dash, so as long as you're not using Unity (i.e. as long as you're not using the "vanilla" flavor) you're "spyware-free".

On a side note [the "spyware" will be disabled by deafult starting from Ubuntu 16.04](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/ubuntu-online-search-feature-disabled-16-04).

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. And nice good to know about the news, not that I intend to use Unity.